# IPython EDITOR defaulting to notepad instead of invoking IDLE [Windows]

Tags: editor, default, ipython, python-idle, notepad

The magic command %edit in IPython defaults to notepad despite setting EDITOR=idle environment variable and [c.]TerminalInteractiveShell.editor in ipython_config.py to idle. I have tried editing all ipython_config.py in subdirectories of my C:\Python27 and setting user as well as system environment variables.
Please advise - is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the Qt console? If so, set `c.IPythonWidget.editor_line` in the config.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm using the Qt console. But setting c.IPythonWidget.editor_line = 'idle -e' didn't help. But setting editor_line in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\qt\console\ipython_widget.py helped! Thank you for your comment, Thomas K.! (Can I reward you for the comment somehow?)